# LDAP login page doesn't work

Tags: php, ldap

I installed PHP on IIS and tested this script, but there is no response after I either enter the correct or incorrect login details.  I try to telnet the ldap server and it does connect properly.

```
<?php
$LDAPserver = "ldap.server.com"; // LDAP server
$LDAPsuffix = "o=companyname, o=companynet"; // LDAP Tree

if (!empty($_POST['login']))
{
    //print_r($_POST);
    echo "<br><br>";

    $userid = $_POST['username']; // User key their userid or email
    $userpassword = $_POST['userpassword']; // User key their password

    $ds=ldap_connect($LDAPserver);  
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    $bind=@ldap_search($ds, $LDAPsuffix, "uid=".$userid);
    if ($bind)
    {
        echo "LDAP bind success <br>";

        $result = @ldap_get_entries($ds, $bind);
        if ($result[0])
        {
            if (@ldap_bind( $ds, $result[0]['dn'], $userpassword))
            {
                echo "User bind success <br>";

                // Can proceed to check database
            }
            else
            {
                echo "User bind failed - Invalid password <br>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "User does not has LDAP account <br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "LDAP bind failed <br>";
    }

    ldap_close($ds);

}


?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login with LDAP Authentication</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="ldaplogin.php" name="passwordChange" method="post">
    <table style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <tr><th>Enter username/email:</th><td><input name="username" type="text" size="0" autocomplete="off" /></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Enter your password:</th><td><input name="userpassword" size="20" type="password" /></td></tr>          
            <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;" >
            <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form> 

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `ldap_bind()` prior to being able to `ldap_search()`. Remove the `@` prepend from the functions so that you can see the errors, warnings, and notices.

Edit: This should do close to what you need, and can be adjusted to fit exactly what you need. This also assumes that your LDAP server does not allow anonymous searches, in case it does, you can rearrange things.

```
$LDAPserver = "ldap.server.com"; // LDAP server
$LDAPsuffix = "o=companyname, o=companynet"; // LDAP Tree

if (!empty($_POST['login'])) {
    echo "<br><br>";

    $userid = $_POST['username']; // User key their userid or email
    $userpassword = $_POST['userpassword']; // User key their password

    $ds = ldap_connect($LDAPserver);  
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ds, "uid=$userid,$LDAPsuffix", $userpassword);
    if ($bind !== false) {
        $search = @ldap_search($ds, $LDAPsuffix, "uid=$userid", array('uid', 'dn'));
        if ($search !== false) {
            $result = @ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
            if (is_array($result) and $result) {
                // Can proceed to check database
            }
            elseif ($result === array()) {
                echo "no results";
            }
            elseif ($result === false) {
                echo "ldap_get_entries() failed: " . ldap_error($ds);
            }
        } else {
            echo "ldap_search() failed: " . ldap_error($ds);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "ldap_bind() failed: " . ldap_error($ds);
    }

    @ldap_unbind($bind);
    @ldap_close($ds);
}
```

Comment: Ok removed @ from the function.  I manage to connect to the ldap now with the correct login details.  What happened with this error msg "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0"  with this line of code: if ($result[0]) when I purposely key in the wrong login details or leaving it blank then click on login button.

Comment: It appears that `$result` is still an array, but it is empty, so it has no `0` index and therefore no results. Try to add another attribute to `ldap_search()`, which is an array of parameters you're searching for. Reference: [ldap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php)

Comment: Thanks, I just add in 'chicken' in this line:
$result = @ldap_get_entries($ds, $bind, 'chicken');

Comment: That function doesn't take a third argument, I was referring to `ldap_search()`, and it should be an array, like `array('chicken')` if you have a `chicken` attribute in LDAP, which would be strange. Stand by, I'll adit my answer with what I think the code ought to look like...